# Can I search for my draft answers?

Tags: support, editing, answers

I googled to know how to get my draft answers.

But I couldn't find a way. I know I can find my draft if I know the question.

In my case I don't remember the question.

Any idea?

Comment: Why would you want the answer when you don't remember the question?

Comment: because I did an effort to get it. but I didn't finish my work and through the weekend I forget what was the question exactly

Comment: Try to filter the question by tags, the age of the question, particular search terms, remember the users who participated in that question... these should help you find that question.

Comment: @Aditya You are right. But I seek for a better way (if exists). I want a query or a url just like this: askubuntu.com/user/../drafts

Comment: If you're using the blackhat logo as your gravatar, you should know how to grep your cookies...

Comment: check the `StackExchange` JS object.